# Google App Engine + AWS S3 file protection!

Tags: java, google-app-engine, amazon-s3

I have an application running on GAE/J that streams video from AWS S3.

I need a solution for protecting the video from being stolen and I found that pre-signed URLs might be it (??).

How can I create pre-signed URLs from GAE/J or there's a better solution to secure the videos?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I need a solution for protecting the
>   video from being stolen and I found
>   that pre-signed URLs might be it (??).

What you're asking for is impossible. Pre-signed URLs will limit the availability of the file to a certain window of time, after which the link will stop working, but there's no way to allow someone to download something with a video player, but not store it to their computer.

Answer (score 0):

Nick, that is not quite right. You can securely stream video with Amazons protected Flash rtmp video streaming service, using Cloudfront. Nobody will be able to download your files. There are tutorials about how to do it on the net. For instance [here](http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/2010/03/how-to-configure-private-content-for.html). You can also go straight to the cloudfront documentation. (Can't post the link here as I'm new to SO and can only post one link).